# YUI TreeView Object

Tags: treeview, yui

Does anyone know how to remove the connecting "lines" between the nodes of the YUI TreeView object? I know I can use the TreeView plugin for jQuery, however, I'm already using YUI as my main js-library and don't really want to include both.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the documentation?

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/treeview/#style

The "Depth spacer styles:" section sounds like what you want.